# SQL Count Distinct Values rows

Tags: sql

I want to count the Shift_Sanitize column as whenever it's value is equal to Compliant. I am using a calculated column.

I am using the below code. Problem is when I enter the below code, the SQL program even counts when the value is "Not Compliant"

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 'id') 
FROM RECF_compliance 
WHERE Shift_Sanitize = 'Compliant';
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Remove the single quotes from id.

Comment: that does not make sense.

Comment: hmm, not sure what DBMS you are using but it is unlikely that single quotes will be used for literals and column name identifiers.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Your code cannot be counting "Non-Compliant".  That is just not possible as expressed.  However, it should always be returning "1" because of this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT 'id')
```

This is counting the distinct values of a constant string, `'id'`.  Presumably, you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
```

Or, if `id` is unique as it usually is in tables, then just count the matching rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
```